# Missing expression Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle trigger and it returns the error

> Additional information: ORA-00936: missing expression

In my TOAD it shows me the below line.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TBL_NEWS_TYPE SET FULLNAME='|| newsName ||' WHERE ID = SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TBL_NEWS_TYPE)';
```

In here **newsName** is varchar2 variable like newsName VARCHAR2(50) / and ID in INTEGER.

Comment: remove ) after TBL_NEWS_TYPE and you should be through

Comment: Why are you using `execute immediate` here? There is no reason for it. And if you do have to for some strange reason, then at least use it with parameters. Concatenating values like that is going to give you trouble in the long run. e,g.: `execute immediate 'update tbl_news_type set fullname = :1 where id = (...)' using newsname;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE TBL_NEWS_TYPE
                   SET FULLNAME='''|| newsName
                   ||''' WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TBL_NEWS_TYPE)'
```

I think you had two problems here:

1) You were missing '(' at the start of the select

2) I think this won't work without putting quote sign wraping the newsName because its a string.

Comment: Now it shows me this exception ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back

Comment: And thats the whole code? are you sure this is the part that throwing the exception?

Comment: ah! got it i used  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; .. now COMMIT missing.. i aded that and working perfectly.